# How to highlight a sentence if it’s in particular font using VBA or .net 2005

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, ms-word

I am working in MSWord 2007 and VBA and also in Visual Studio 2005.
In my MSWord document contains different fonts I want to highlight the text which is in particular font.
Like if one sentence in Arial then I want to highlight that sentence alone.

Comment: Use MS Word to record a macro. It will allow you to select formats to find. The resulting code will give you various keywords and a start on coding your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you want to find all sections of text with a given font.
In the `docx` format which is used in MSWord 2007 a section of text with common properties is called a `run`, specified by the `<w:r>` tag ([ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Office%20Open%20XML%20Formats/Draft%20ECMA-376%203rd%20edition,%20March%202011/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%203%20-%20Markup%20Compatibility%20and%20Extensibility.pdf) page 33). A runs rich formatting (including its font) is stored in the `<w:rPr>` tag, specifically in the `<w:rFonts>` tag. So, to find a section of text with a given font we look for a `<w:rFonts>` tag with the appropriate font information.

The `<w:rFonts>` tag is formatted as such (with some irrelevant properties dropped):

```
 <w:rFonts w:ascii=”FontName” 
           w:cs=”FontName” 
           w:eastAsia=”FontName” 
           w:hAnsi=”FontName”/>
```

The attributes correspond to different encodings:

- `w:ascii` corresponds to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
- `w:cs`corresponds to [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters that require [Complex formatting techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout)
- `w:eastAsia` corresponds to characters in the East Asian Unicode range
- `w:hAnsi` corresponds to any character in the Unicode range that does not fall into one of the categories above

Assuming you don't have any Chinese, Arabic or other forms of complex text in your documents you can safely ignore the `w:cs` and `w:eastAsia` attributes.

To recap - we need to find all `<w:rFonts>` with `w:ascii` or `w:hAnsi` attributes corresponding to the needed font or in other words `<w:rFonts w:ascii="Needed Font" w:hAnsi="Needed Font">`.

Now, if you aren't familiar with the `docx` format, it's actually a package of several files including XML files ([more info on the docx document structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2006/06/23/getstartedwithopenxmlfileformats.aspx)). We could use `System.IO.Packaging` and XML parsing classes to work with `docx` documents, but we have a useful abstraction from Microsoft - The [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) which gives us a nice class hierarchy for working with `docx` files:

- [WordprocessingDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.aspx)
- [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc802400.aspx)
- [Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.body_members.aspx)
- [Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph_members.aspx)
- [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.run_members.aspx)
- [RunProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runproperties_members.aspx)
- [RunFonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runfonts_members.aspx)

Once we get to the `RunFonts` class we have two properties relevant to us - `RunFonts.Ascii` and `RunFonts.HighAnsi`. How do we get there? The following code snippet demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace WordProcessingEx
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = /*obtain path to file here*/;

            using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                // Get all paragraphs
                var p = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().First();
                var r = from para in p
                        from run in para.Elements<Run>()
                        where run.RunProperties.RunFonts.ASCII ="NeededFont" || run.RunProperties.RunFonts.HighAnsi = "NeededFont"
                        select run;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have all runs with the appropriate font we need to highlight them. This is accomplished with the `<w:highlight>` tag and its `w:val` property. For example - `<w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>`.

The following code snippet demonstrates:

```
foreach (var run in r)
{
    run.RunProperties.Highlight.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("w:val", null, "yellow"));
}
```

(This comes inside the `using` block above, right after the LINQ query)

After all of this, we are done. Once execution leaves the `using` block, every run that uses the selected font is highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, Thanks a lot @Michael Dmitry Azarkevic this is what i want to know.. thanks for ur deep explanation. But i am using only visual studio 2005 i can't write these code into that what shld i do..

Comment: First of all, VS2005 suports the .NET framework 2.0 by default. Is this the framework you're using? If so, the code above will not work (`System.IO.Packaging` on top of which the OpenXML SDK is built only works with .NET 3.0 or above)
If you have this old version of the .NET frameowrk, you'll have to find a library for XML parsing for .NET 2.0 or better yet, switch to .NET 3.5 SP1 or above.
If you have a newer version, have you downloaded the SDK and installed it?
Have you imported the assembly into your project?
Have you imported the namespaces? (`using` statemnets)

Comment: Then you should download the SDK, install it, import the assemblies and import the namespaces. Here's how you do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456488.aspx